# Understanding ARM assembly instructions and C/C++ pointers

Tags: c++, linux, pointers

I am trying to decode the assembly instruction that operates on address, 16 bit ARM thumb instruction. So, I don't think I should care about data type. Because I'm only interested in the 16 bits store there. I have separate interpreter to make sense of those bits, I don't want to use that as data anyway.

If I have a pointer `p` and I want to read 4 bytes (i.e data from `p` to `p+3` address). Will casting `p` to `int *` and dereferencing give me the data?

Comment: What is the type of `p` ?

Comment: `memcpy` into an `int32_t`?

Comment: Also please don't use both C and C++ tags. While there are some syntactical similarities they are both very different languages. Only use the tag for the language you're actually programming in.

Comment: By the way, data is stored at *increasing* addresses in memory. It has never been the opposite. Increasing a pointer will always increase the address it points to. A pointer always point to the *beginning* of the data being pointed to.

Answer (score 4):

You have a pointer *to-some-type*. Pointer arithmetic and dereferencing honors the data type.

**Please note,** you can only access the stored value of any variable (object) by an lvalue expression that has either a compatible type or a character pointer. Blindly forcing a pointer to cast to a different non-compatible type and attempt to dereference that will violate the strict aliasing rule and you'll face  [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>   the following types:<sup>88)</sup>
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the
>   object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the
>   effective type of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
>   members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>
> — a character type.

You can however, always use a `char *` to point to any type and dereference and increment (and repeat) to get the individual values for the bytes but you need to take care of endianness yourself.

Related, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.3

> [....] When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type,
>   the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the
>   result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.